# ASP .net Web Api downloading and viewing images

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to download images from a server and display them in the browser. But when I enter the url in the browser (localhost:port/api/service/imageID), the download box appears asking me wether to save or open the image. But I want the image to be straight displayed in the browser.
This is my controller 'Get' method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
  HttpResponseMessage response;
  var image = _repository.RetrieveImage(id);

  if (image == null)
  {
    response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  }
  else
  {
    response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(image.ImageData));
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(image.ImageData);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = image.OriginalFileName;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(image.Mime);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = image.ImageData.Length;
  }
  return response;
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that you assign the `Content` property twice. Have you tried just using `StreamContent`?

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't work. I will try the answer from DigitalID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the "attachment" content disposition header. Using that header instructs browsers to download the specified file instead of showing it inline.

```
 response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, note that removing the `Content-Disposition` will also remove any hint of the file's name when saved using "Save As" context menu, and a filename will be suggested based on the URL, which in this case will be something like "42.jpg", because the last part of the URL is an ID. If you want to preserve the file name during save, change the `Content-Disposition` to "inline":

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
{
    FileName = image.OriginalFileName,
    Size = image.ImageData.Length
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For you scenario, i think you could just return a StreamContent and provide the appropriate content-type header of this content. (ex: image/jpeg)